# When I run my code, i get a segfault, but when the debugger runs it, it says there is no issue

Tags: c, gdb

I'm doing an assignment that is working with shared memory, and i'm getting segfaults whenever I run the code. So i tried using the GDB debugger to see where the fault is occurring,but when it runs the code, it exits normally and says its fine. i pasted what wasin the terminal below

```
./main
This is the cb 16669520, This is the dbInfo 2117869600, and this is the db 2117869608
this is the number of processes 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

the first two lines it prints out are fine, but the code never reaches the end of the main. THen when I run the debugger...

```
gdb ./main
(gdb) run
Starting program: /*path*/ 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
This is the cb -8848, This is the dbInfo -243544032, and this is the db -243544024
this is the number of processes 2
The code got this far[Inferior 1 (process 15840) exited normally]
(gdb) backtrace
No stack.
```

Comment: This happens sometimes with undefined behavior: sometimes it crashes, sometimes not.  Try running your program under `valgrind` or build it with "Undefined Behavior Sanitizer" and/or "Address Sanitizer" to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: A bug that goes away when looking at it with a debugger is commonly known as a Heisenbug :-)  Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can help you debug the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your program with `valgrind`. It will detect invalid reads and writes to memory, tell you where they happen and, most likely, be helpful enough to tell you exactly what line caused them. One of these errors is what's causing your program to segfault.

Don't forget to add the `-ggdb3` flag when compiling your program :)

Answer (score 0):

If valgrind does not help (usually it wlll), consider enabling warning at compile time. If possible, the compile should be 'clean', without any warning. GCC can detect many common errors.

```
gcc -Wall ... file.c

# or even
gcc -Wall -Wextra ... file.c
```

from gcc man:

> ```
>   -Wall
>        This enables all the warnings about constructions that some users
>        consider questionable, and that are easy to avoid (or modify to
>        prevent the warning), even in conjunction with macros.  This also
>        enables some language-specific warnings described in C++ Dialect
>        Options and Objective-C and Objective-C++ Dialect Options.
>   -Wextra
>        This enables some extra warning flags that are not enabled by
>        -Wall. (This option used to be called -W.  The older name is still
>        supported, but the newer name is more descriptive.)
> ```